# Activity Timeline is not Displaying in Community

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, activities

I've followed this Knowledge Article, and nothing seems to work. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350558&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1

Following the KA: I went to Setup -> Record Page Settings -> And have "Activity Timeline" checked. I also went My Avatar -> Record Page Settings -> And have "Activity Timeline" checked.

On an "Activity" tab on a Contact record page I see an Activity Timeline just fine. I can't figure out why it doesn't show in a Community. After the community is published the component is completely absent. I am testing as System Administrator, and have assigned/created tasks and events to myself. Not sure what else to look for. Org Wide Sharing Rules show "private". I changed it to "Controlled by Parent" but nothing helps. This is also "Health Cloud" if that makes a difference.

Fig 1: Works On a record page

[image]

Fig 2. Component dragged on to a page

[image]

Fig 3 - Org Wide Sharing rules
[image: Org Wide Sharing Rules]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe the org-wide sharing permissions you have assigned to the Activity object for external users.

Comment: @DavidCheng - Editing the post. It's set to private, but the only other option is :"Controlled by Parent" and nothing changeable for External Users. See screenshot in Edit.

Comment: Also, I tested as myself. Same result.

Comment: @ESRouter I believe you are using the activities component from the builder. You need to add it to the "record detail" page in the community for it to show the information related to the specific record. I tried it on my community and could succeed.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, there is no relevant data for the "activity" as it is not mapped to any specific record.

You need to add the Activity component to the "record detail" page in the community for it to show the information related to the specific record.

The same applies to other components like Feed, Feed publisher, Feed compact...

Attached a screenshot from my org where I could add the component without the error.
[image: activity component in record detail page]