# Pass ContactId to Record Detail component on User Page

Tags: lightning, lightning-app-builder, lightning-record-page

I am trying to show some Contact / Account fields on User Profile page in Community. Please refer to the pic below
[image]

Is there a way to do this?
I am aware that there are different pages like Account Information and Settings. If I wanted to add those pages under user Profile page what is the best way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/336807/activity-timeline-is-not-displaying-in-community/340769#340769 ?

Comment: @Swetha thanks but that did not answer it.